# Assembly compiled executable using INT 0x80 on Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux doesn't produce output

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been looking at a tutorial for assembly, and I'm trying to get a hello world program to run. I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

Here is the assembly:

```
section .text
    global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
    len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

I am using these commands to create the executable:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o
ld -o hello hello.o -m elf_x86_64
```

And I run it using:

```
./hello
```

The program then seems to run without a segmentation fault or error, but it produces no output.

I can't figure out why the code won't produce an output, but I wonder if using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows has anything to do with it? Why doesn't it produce output and how can I fix it?

Comment: The fact that you're using the 32-bit system call interface in a 64-bit executable may have something to do with it.

Comment: I've read that Ubuntu-on-Windows doesn't support 32-bit executables at all; maybe they don't support the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI in 64-bit executables either.  Your code looks like it would work on Linux, where [the `int 0x80` ABI is supported (but *not* recommended) in 64-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code).

Comment: Oh, or is `msg` located at an address which doesn't fit into 32 bits, in your 64-bit binary?  That would explain it, although that's not the usual layout.  Try using `strace ./hello` or single-step with GDB to see the error return value in `eax`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Related: WSL2 does allow 32-bit user-space programs, WSL1 doesn't.  See *[Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61300194/does-wsl-2-really-support-32-bit-program)* re: making sure you're actually using WSL2.  The rest of this answer was written before WLS2 existed.

---

The issue is with Ubuntu for Windows (Windows Subsystem for Linux version 1). It only supports the 64-bit `syscall` interface and [**not** the 32-bit x86 `int 0x80`](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/537) system call mechanism.

Besides not being able to use `int 0x80` (32-bit compatibility) in 64-bit binaries, Ubuntu on Windows (WSL1) [doesn't support running 32-bit executables](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13377507-please-add-32-bit-elf-support-to-the-kernel) either.  (Same as if you'd built a real Linux kernel [without `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/AMD64/FAQ#What_kernel_to_use.3F), like some Gentoo users do.)

---

You need to convert from using `int 0x80` to [`syscall`](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf). It's not difficult. A different set of registers are used for a `syscall` and the system call numbers are different from their 32-bit counterparts. [Ryan Chapman's blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) has information on the `syscall` interface, the system calls, and their parameters. `Sys_write` and `Sys_exit` are defined this way:

> ```
> %rax  System call  %rdi               %rsi              %rdx          %r10 %r8 %r9
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 0     sys_read     unsigned int fd    char *buf         size_t count          
> 1     sys_write    unsigned int fd    const char *buf   size_t count
> 60    sys_exit     int error_code
> ```

Using `syscall` also clobbers *RCX* and the *R11* registers. They are considered volatile. Don't rely on them being the same value after the `syscall`.

Your code could be modified to be:

```
section .text
    global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov rsi,msg     ;message to write
    mov edi,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,edi     ;system call number (sys_write)
    syscall         ;call kernel

    xor edi, edi    ;Return value = 0
    mov eax,60      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    syscall         ;call kernel

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
    len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

Note: in 64-bit code if the **destination** register of an instruction is 32-bit (like *EAX*, *EBX*, *EDI*, *ESI* etc) the [processor zero extends the result into the upper 32-bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/3857942) of the 64-bit register. `mov edi,1` has the same effect as `mov rdi,1`.

---

This answer isn't a primer on writing 64-bit code, only about using the `syscall` interface. If you are interested in the nuances of writing code that calls the *C* library, and conforms to the 64-bit System V ABI there are reasonable tutorials to get you started like [Ray Toal's NASM tutorial](http://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/nasmtutorial/). He discusses stack alignment, the red zone, register usage, and a basic overview of the 64-bit System V calling convention.

Comment: I would also warn about different ABI in 64b, where putting arguments into registers is probably the easy part to grasp, but the stack alignment and red zone may be a bit more tricky for somebody just starting to learn assembly. Generally I would rather suggest to compile as 32b binary in answer to question like this, but that's not an option in windows, where only 64b linux is supported)

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out in comments by Ross Ridge, don't use 32-bit calling of kernel functions when you compile 64bit.

Either compile for 32bit or "translate" the code into 64 bit syscalls.
Here is what that could look like:

```
section .text
    global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov rdx,len     ;message length
    mov rsi,msg     ;message to write
    mov rdi,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov rax,1       ;system call number (sys_write)
    syscall         ;call kernel

    mov rax,60      ;system call number (sys_exit)
    mov rdi,0       ;add this to output error code 0(to indicate program terminated without errors)
    syscall         ;call kernel

section .data
    msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
    len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

Comment: Unlike most Linux systems, building as 32-bit is not an option on WSL: the `int 0x80` ABI is just plain not supported, even for 32-bit executables.  So it's like a Linux kernel built without `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION`.